# Getting error NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'login' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/$login/$']

Tags: python, django, django-urls

URLS.PY

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(),name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(),name='logout'),
    url(r'^signup/$',views.SignUp.as_view(),name='signup'),
]
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Star Social</title>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'simple_clone/css/master.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
          <nav class="navbar mynav" role="navigation" id="navbar">
            <div class="container">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Star Social</a>
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Post</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Groups</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Create Group</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}">Logout</a>
                </li>
                {% else %}
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Groups</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:signup'%}">Sign Up</a>
                </li>
                {% endif %}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>

     {% block content%}
     {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

On trying to access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

> Request Method:   GET
>   Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>   Django Version:   1.11.29
>   Exception Type:   NoReverseMatch
>   Exception Value:
>   Reverse for 'login' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/$login/$']

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your login url should be:

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Log In</a>
```

As it is under `app_name='accounts'`.

Secondly, I am guessing you have put a`$` sign at the end of the url where you have included accounts urls. Please fix that by

```
url(r'^accounts/',include('accounts.url')),
```

Because [`$`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) means end of a regex.

Comment: Thank you for your information. But i am still have the same issue

Comment: Thank you for your information. But i am still have the same issue NoReverseMatch at /
'accounts' is not a registered namespace
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
'accounts' is not a registered namespace. accounts is the app name of my project.  When i put this url comment in my project urls.py file path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')), i get the circular import error.could you please suggest thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the app_name, in your case is `accounts`, in the login link.

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Log In</a>
```